# Finding the limit of a step function f(x)

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

I need to find and prove the possible existence of this limit :

The function $f(x)$ is defined as follows:
$$f(x) =
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
1, x < -2 \\ 
0, x > -2 \\
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Does $f(x)$ have a limit as $x → −2$ ? If it does, state the value of the limit, briefly
justifying your answer. If there is no limit, briefly state why not.

I've tried using the $(\epsilon, δ)$-definition definition of the limit : 
$\lim_{x\to-2} f(x) = a$ if for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $δ$ s.t. $|f(x) - a| < \epsilon$ for all $x$ s.t. $|x + 2| < δ$.

But I struggle because of two points :

1. I am not sure how to operate on a step function such as this one and use it as part of the $(\epsilon, δ)$-definition of a limit.
2. There are two limits, from both left and right which exist, but I am not sure if this answers the question "Does $f(x)$ have a limit as $x → −2 ?$"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The limit does not exist since the left and right limit are not the same

Comment: If the left and right limits are unequal, the limit doesn’t exist.

Comment: For a $\lim_{x \rightarrow -2} f(x)$ to exist, we require that $\lim_{x \rightarrow -2^+} f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow -2^-} f(x)$.  If the left hand and right hand limits agree, then we say the limit exists.  If they do not agree, then the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume it has a limit
$$\lim_{x\to-2}f(x)=L$$

So, by sequential charactetisation of the limit, for any sequence $ (x_n) $ which goes to $ -2 $, the sequence of the images $ (f(x_n)) $ should go to $ L .$

But we have
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}f(-2-\frac 1n)=1$$
and
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}f(-2+\frac 1n)=0$$

Done.